# How to change corb thread count on the fly

Tags: marklogic-corb

How can I reduce thread count during corb running.  I was trying below but not work  Thanks

```
[linux1]$corb thread-count 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear what the `corb` process is that you are running, to know how it may be passing any commandline switches and using them to invoke the CoRB process.

There is a **THREAD-COUNT** option that can be specified as either a system property, main arg, or as an option within the **OPTIONS-FILE** or **COMMAND-FILE**.

CoRB needs options specified through one or more of the following mechanisms:

1. command-line parameters
2. Java system properties ex: `-DXCC-CONNECTION-URI=xcc://user:password@localhost:8202`
3. As properties file in the class path specified using `-DOPTIONS-FILE=myjob.properties`. Relative and full file system paths are also supported.

If specified in more than one place, a command line parameter takes precedence over a Java system property, which take precedence over a property from the **OPTIONS-FILE** properties file.

There are a couple of ways to adjust the thread count dynamically, as the job is executing:

- If you set the [**COMMAND-FILE**](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#COMMAND-FILE) to point to a properties file (doesn't have to exist when the job is started, but can be the [**OPTIONS-FILE**](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#OPTIONS-FILE)), then CoRB will watch that file and will update the number of threads if you happen to change the [**THREAD-COUNT**](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#THREAD-COUNT)
- If you have enabled the UI, by specifying the [**JOB-SERVER-PORT**](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#JOB-SERVER-PORT) with an available port or range of ports, then you could change the thread count from the UI (URL gets logged on startup), and could also make the same HTTP calls that the UI does.

Comment: Hi Mr. Hansen, that's mean I can modify -thread_count value in the properties during corb running background?

Comment: Yes, if you configure your job to watch that properties file as the COMMAND-FILE

Comment: I tried to setup properties. But I'm not sure is it correct setup COMMAND-FILE option? Can you please me an sample.

#SETUP CORB PROPERTIES
XCC-CONNECTION-URI=xcc://user:password@localhost:8000/testcase
THREAD-COUNT=18
URIS-MODULE=uris.xqy|ADHOC
PROCESS-MODULE=uris-process.xqy|ADHOC
EXPORT-FILE-NAME=Archive.txt
PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchToFileTask
PRE-BATCH-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.PreBatchUpdateFileTask
EXPORT-FILE-TOP-CONTENT=This report list duplicate records found.
EXPORT_FILE_AS_ZIP=true
COMMAND-FILE=/corb/code/uris-archive.properties

Comment: That looks right. If you are using an OPTIONS-FILE then it's just another property in the properties file. You can either set the full path, or just filename relative from where the CoRB process present working directory. There is an example on the wiki: https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/wiki/Example:-Using-COMMAND-FILE-to-pause,-resume,-stop-and-change-THREAD-COUNT

Comment: Thank you so much Sir.